# Google storage.Client throwing .__int__ error: takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage, credentials, google-authentication

When trying to authenticate my **local Google credentials** to access Google Cloud Storage I'm given the error:

> TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

This happens if I run:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client=storage.Client()
```

I've tried adding

```
credentials, project = google.auth.default(
     scopes=[
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control', 
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only', 
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write'
     ]
)
```

and

```
storage_client = storage.Client.__init__(self, credentials=credentials, project=project, client_info=None)
```

but have not been able to resolve the error. Any help appreciated! Let me know if I can provide more context.

The libraries I have installed are:

- google-api-core           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
- google-api-python-client  1.12.11                  pypi_0    pypi
- google-auth               1.35.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
- google-auth-httplib2      0.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
- google-auth-oauthlib      0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
- google-cloud              0.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
- google-cloud-bigquery     3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
- google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
- google-cloud-core         2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
- google-cloud-sdk          387.0.0          py39h6e9494a_0
  conda-forge
- google-cloud-storage      2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
- google-crc32c             1.1.2            py39h9ed2024_0
- google-resumable-media    2.3.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0
  conda-forge
- googleapis-common-protos  1.56.2           py39h6e9494a_0
  conda-forge

Answer (score 0):

Try not to call `__init__` directly when instantiating the storage client. Also, note that you put `self` as a parameter, which is why you are sending one additional positional argument.

Let's try removing those additional args:

```
storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!
I was able to resolve this issue with this code:

```
credentials, project = google.auth.default()

client = storage.Client(project=project)
```